# Record video with webcam and save it in java

Tags: java, opencv, webcam, javacv

My goal is to capture a video with a webcam and save it. I am already able to take photos with the webcam.

Therefore, I use the webcam API provided by sarxos. I now want to stick together images to get a video. Up to now I have used OpenCV for this purpose. Unfortunately, the video seems to be speeded up and is blue.

```
      Runnable recordVideo = () -> {
            final int FPS = 30;
            final int WIDTH = 640;
            final int HEIGHT = 480;

            File output = new File('test.avi');
            webcam.setViewSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
            webcam.open();
            Java2DFrameConverter java2DFrameConverter = new Java2DFrameConverter();

            OpenCVFrameRecorder recorder = new OpenCVFrameRecorder(output, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
            recorder.setFrameRate(FPS);
            recorder.setVideoCodec(opencv_videoio.VideoWriter.fourcc((byte) 'M', (byte) 'J', (byte) 'P', (byte) 'G'));


            try {
                recorder.start();

                while (true) {
                    if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                        break;
                    }
                    BufferedImage image = webcam.getImage();

                    recorder.record(java2DFrameConverter.convert(image));
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000 / (long) FPS);

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                recorder.stop();
                recorder.release();
                log.info("[RecorderService] Video recorded in file: " + output.getAbsolutePath());
                webcam.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };

        recordVideoThread = new Thread(recordVideo);
        recordVideoThread.start();
```

pom.xml dependencies

```
            <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
            <artifactId>javacv-platform</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.sarxos</groupId>
            <artifactId>webcam-capture</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.12</version>
        </dependency>
```

How can I slow the capturing speed to real time and change the video to the original color?

Comment: It seems the FPS you set in video recorder is not the same with the FPS of the webcam, so you should first get the FPS of the camera and then set it to the recorder, maybe the FPS is about 15 or something less than 30 so it goes fast.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working. Even if i change the FPS to 15 or 10 the video is still speed up.